# How can we be sure of the efficiency of a neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, normalization

I trained a Forward Neural Net for binary classification and I got an accuracy of 83%, which (I hope)I'm going to improve later by changing parameters in inputs.  But some tests make me feel confused :

> My dataset length is 671 so I divide it as 513 train set, 58 Validation set and 100 test set

1. When I change the size of my sets (Train, Validation, Test), the accuracy score can decrease to some very low scores like 40%
2. The neural net is supposed to learn from the train set but when I test, after the training, with the same Train set and not the Test set, I thought that the model should score 100 %, because he just learned from it, watched it, but it only improves a few with 87% ...

I'm a beginner in ML so I don't know if it's normal or not, I'm just curious and wanna catch all the small things to know, to understand perfectly what I'm doing. I guess it's maybe the **normalization** of my vectors sets, but I don't know very much about it. I can share you my full code if you want to, but as every neural net, it's quite long but easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by many people 3:1:1 (60:20:20 = train-validate-test) ratio is a thumb rule to split data, if you are playing with small data set it better to stick with 80:20 or 70:30 just train-test,I usually go for 90:10 ratio for better results.

Before you start with classification, first check whether your data set is balanced or imbalanced ( there should not be less example belongs to one class as compared to other ) because even though it gives you good accuracy it will mislead the results.

If data set is imbalanced, pre-processed data set with sampling algorithm  (for e.g SMOTE) and re-sample it. It will create equal sets of examples for class based on neighbors.

As correctly mentioned in other answer, use cross validation classification such as K-fold. The concept of cross validation is done to tweak the parameters used for training in order to optimize its accuracy and to nullify the effect of over-fitting on the training data, it also remove the noise in data set. I usually go for 10-fold cross validation where data set divided in 10 partition and in each iteration 1/10 partition use as test and rest as training. Take the average of the 10 computations to get a good estimate of the performance of your classifier.

Comment: I don't understand the sampling algorithm ... I mean , SMOTE is going to give me my test set the same shape as train set , and doing so , there will be no more ratio of 80:20 ?? Can you explain it to me please ? (I follow this [example for SMOTE](https://www.kaggle.com/qianchao/smote-with-imbalance-data)  @VimalThilak

Comment: No, It will create more examples for minority class. for e.g your original data set have class 1 : 1000 and class 0 : 10, then based on the neighborhood it will create the more example for class 0 and make it balanced data sets.  In your example for SMOTE, you can see count of labels of minority class has been increased and overall data size also also increased.

Comment: Before OverSampling, counts of label '1': [345]
Before OverSampling, counts of label '0': [199019] 

After OverSampling, the shape of train_X: (398038, 29)
After OverSampling, the shape of train_y: (398038,) 

After OverSampling, counts of label '1': 199019
After OverSampling, counts of label '0': 199019

Comment: okay so if I understand well , it will duplicate some data to have as much label 1 than label 0 , well , I've done it , and I still find approximately the same accuracy , 85% , but of course I had to change some parameters like the numbers of neurons in my hidden layers

Comment: For your clarity, you still going to have ratio formula for train / test.                               
Note : Please measure your performance by using metrics such MCC, F-Score etc.

Comment: okay , I hope I'll got some good result too with these , I will let you know ! Also , I don't know if it's the good way but I decide the numbers of neurons in the hidden layers etc ... by some loop for and take the best result , is there a easier way ?

Comment: I am yet to experiment with Neural Network, but once I do. I will definitely get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things to address here.

1- This is a very very small dataset for NN, so it is not surprising that the results vary that much when changing the size of the sets.

2- You are not supposed to get 100% on the train set. If you do, then your model has severly overfitted and it will not be able to generalize to new examples.

3- The best way to get a good estimation of the generalization performance with such a small dataset is with K-fold cross validation (I should say, arguably the best, but it certainly is in my opinion the easiest). Basically instead of separating the dataset like you did, you would train for example on 80% of the dataset and test on the 20%, then train on another 80% and test on a different 20%, 5 times until all examples have been tested on (there are some variations of this). Read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

4- For such a small dataset, imo another algorithm may perform better.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help , but what did you mean  exactly in 4th point ? what kind of algorithm ?  What size would be reasnoable and "quiet welll" ?

Comment: Well there are a lot of algorithms available (if you want some out of the box I suggest you visit sklearn which implement quite a few). I'm guessing you're doing binary classification based on the fact you used accuracy as a score, so maybe try SVM or linear regression, these usually work good for binary classification with small dataset. Random Forests is also always a valid option, especially if you have a lot of features!

Comment: I already tried linear regression but it did'nt work well , I'm almost sure that I need neural net because linear regression is just about stats , it learns nothing and my classification needs it. but it's not easy to have a big dataset for my problem ..

Comment: Sorry I meant Logistic regression not linear. Also just fyi everything in machine learning is just about stats. It would be easier if I had more information about the problem

Comment: What benefit can there be in testing [sic] before all training unless you modify the net after the test via some means other than training?

Answer (score 1):

OP: Your questions are very good for someone that's just getting started in machine learning.

1. Have you ensured that the distribution of your training and test dataset are similar? I would try to keep the number of samples per class (label) about equal if possible. For instance, if your training set is severely imbalanced then your prediction algorithm might tend to favor the label that shows up more often.
2. I think you are on the right track to overfit your model to ensure your neural net architecture, training and whatever else is setup correctly. Are you using regularization? If so, I think you might want to remove that to see if your model can fit to your training dataset. I understand that this goes against what the accepted answer's #2 suggests but this is a useful way to debug your setup
3. How good are the labels for your dataset? If you have any noise in your labels then that would affect the accuracy of your classifier
4. You could also try transfer learning if you cannot get more training data

Comment: You were right , my dataset was **imbalanced** (70% of label 0 in test set and only 40% on the train set , so yes , label 1 is favored ) . I'm trying with **SMOTE** algorithm as @SUN suggested , but I thought that we wanted same proportions in terms of % of labels in the test and train set , because I saw that SMOTE is going to give the same shape to my Datasets , so **no more ratio** of 90-10% , is that normal ? Can I balance it myself ?  **3)** I have some noises in my labels ,  can't do anything about it , but yes for sure it would affect the accuracy.

Comment: @Benech17 I can only provide general directions here. It looks like you are already trying to rebalance your classes which is good. Other options include:
- stratified sampling
- tinkering with your loss function to account for the imbalanced nature of your dataset

Before doing all of this, can you establish a baseline for not just accuracy but also what the precision, recall and AUC are for your classifier?